# jQuery AJAX call returning 403 Forbidden error when passing Rgraph image data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am working on a project, where I have implemented a couple of graphs/charts using the **Rgraph** PHP library. In my script I do the following for the graphs:

1. Calculate the graph points and draw the graph using the Rgraph `Draw()` method.
2. Create an image data variable using the `canvas.toDataURL()` method.
3. Pass this image data variable to the server using jQuery AJAX `$.post()` method.
4. Save the image to server via the PHP script.

Everything in this solution works great on my localhost, however on the development server, the AJAX request that passes the image data returns a `403 Error`.

I logged the data on both the client and server side to determine the issue. Client side logging confirms the imageData variable being passed looks correct. However server side logging confirms that the **imageData** variable being passed is what is causing the issue.

There was a [very similar question posted last year about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26228813/jquery-ajax-request-return-forbidden-403-in-cakephp-project), however they were unable to determine the root cause of this. Can anyone help point me in the right direction of resolving this?

I'm thinking this is a possible data encoding issue, but if this the case, why does it work on one server and not the other?

**My Relevant Javascript:**

```
radar.Set('chart.contextmenu', [
     ['Get PNG', RGraph.showPNG],
     null,
     ['Cancel', function () {}]
]);

radar.Draw();   

var imageData = radar.canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

console.log('imageData: ' + imageData);
console.log('filename: ' + 'tmpRadar<?php echo $us['UsersSurvey']['user_id']; ?>-<?php echo $survey['Survey']['id']; ?>.png');

$.post("/Surveys/save_chart", { 
    src     : imageData, 
    filename: 'tmpRadar<?php echo $us['UsersSurvey']['user_id']; ?>-<?php echo $survey['Survey']['id']; ?>.png'
});
```

**Client Side Logging:**

```
imageData: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABLAAAAOECAYAAACxbcj6AAAgAElEQ…AgQIAAgVECAqxR49YsAQIECBAgQIAAAQIECBAgQKCfwP8CXHJ+WDHVMbcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
filename: tmpRadar19-1.png
POST http://website.com/Surveys/save_chart 403 (Forbidden)
```

**PHP Function called by AJAX:**

```
public function save_chart() {
    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->log('request data: '.print_r($this->request->data, true));

        $filename = $this->request->data['filename'];

        $src     = $this->request->data['src'];
        $src     = substr($src, strpos($src, ",") + 1);
        $decoded = base64_decode($src);

        $fp = fopen(WWW_ROOT.'files/graphs/'.$filename,'wb');
        if(fwrite($fp, $decoded)) {
            fclose($fp);
            return json_encode(array('success' => '1'));
        } else {
            fclose($fp);
            return json_encode(array('success' => '0'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show both logging client side and server side (both one that working and one that does't)

Comment: have you checked the apache log files ? I think they might give some insight about the problem

Comment: Have you verified this is not a CORS issue? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) isn't the issue here (which it doesn't sound like it is given that it's working fine on your localhost and that it sounds like your POSTing to the same domain from which you received the original GET), it's likely a misconfiguration between Apache on your localhost and devbox. Given that the issue is only with your base 64 encoded image POST, it's likely too large so apache is rejecting it.

Per [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6135427/increasing-the-maximum-post-size), try setting the following in either your php.ini:

```
post_max_size=20M
upload_max_filesize=20M
```

or in .htaccess / httpd.conf / virtualhost:

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize=20M
```

Note that I can't tell you for sure if this is the cause until you post the apache error log.

Answer (score 2):

It’s to do with `mod_security` (an Apache module) and the `http://` part of the URL.

You have two options here,

- Modify the Apache module
- Client side workaround

Try removing `imagedata` from the form you are posting, and it should submit.

Source: [403-on-form-submit](http://edrackham.com/javascript/solution-to-form-submit-403-error/)

Comment: You are probably right.
So another option is to use FormData to submit the file. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax#answer-5976031

Answer (score -2):

Your use of data in .post() is a little off. If you are trying to pass a JSON object as the data for the second argument of .post(), you need to properly form it into a JSON string. Try wrapping your dictionary with JSON.stringify(). It'll take your javascript value {key1: value1, key2: value2} and format it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```
$.post("/Surveys/save_chart", JSON.stringify(
  { 
    src     : imageData, 
    filename: 'tmpRadar<?php echo $us['UsersSurvey']['user_id']; ?>-<?php echo $survey['Survey']['id']; ?>.png'
  }
) //end stringify 
)//end post;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this does not change anything for me. Also, the jquery `$.post` method can take a string or an object as the second parameter. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/