# Ckeditor upload image return 403 forbidden error on codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor with codeigniter;

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {


  config.width = '68%';

  config.toolbarGroups= [

{name:"styles","groups":["styles"]},
{name: 'basicstyles', groups: [ 'basicstyles', 'cleanup' ] },
{name: "links"},
{name: "paragraph", groups: [ 'list', 'indent', 'blocks', 'align'] },
'/',
{name: 'colors' },
{name: 'clipboard', groups: [ 'clipboard', 'undo' ] },
{name:"insert","groups":["insert"]},
  ];

  config.extraPlugins = 'mathjax,codesnippet,autogrow,colordialog,tableresize';

  config.codeSnippet_theme = 'zenburn';

  config.autoGrow_maxHeight = 600;


 config.filebrowserUploadUrl = '../Ckeditor/do_upload';
};
```

this is the config.js file of Ckeditor

```
class Ckeditor extends CI_Controller{

  public function __construct(){

parent::__construct();
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->helper('form');
}

  public function do_upload(){

$config['upload_path'] = './resources/uploads/';

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';

$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);

$funcNum = $this->input->get('CKEditorFuncNum');

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('upload')){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    $message = 'fail';
    $url = '';
}
else
{
   $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
   $message = 'success';
   $url = base_url().'resources/uploads/'. $this->upload->data()['file_name'];
}

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction($funcNum, '$url', '$message');</script>";
 }

  public function index(){

echo 'this page is used for file upload';
$this->load->view('form', array('error' => ''));

  }
 }
```

the do_upload works fine when I'm using  ,but for the CKeditor each time I'm try to upload an image .I get a 403 POST

```
http://localhost/ci/index.php/admin/Ckeditor/do_upload?CKEditor=editor1&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=zh-cn 403 (Forbidden)
```

how to solve this problem, it's already annoy me for a day..Is it because of lack of this hidden fields?

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="3be92cbaaba15d7d08dd7affad23abfd" style="display:none;" />
```

but how can i make ckeditor to work.cause apprently I can't control the form ckeditor generated to upload image?

_____________________________update_____________________________________________

when I set the

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

in the codeigniter's config.php. I don't have problem upload image.but I want that set to TRUE.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross Site Request Forgery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
| checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
| recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
|
| 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
| 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
| 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
| 'csrf_regenerate' = Regenerate token on every submission
| 'csrf_exclude_uris' = Array of URIs which ignore CSRF checks
*/
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

So my problem may be temporary disable the csrf_protection on the Codeigniter.
but why should I temporary disable that?
Is there other way to solve the problem instead of disable the csrf_protection on a single url like below.

```
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array(
  'admin/Ckeditor/do_upload',
  ''
);
```

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30409755/3113793)

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here.because when I close the csrf protection I can upload the image. but That's not what I want to do.